# Give names to parameters of Fn bound

Tags: rust

I have a function which takes a function as input:

```
fn foo<F : Fn(usize, usize, usize) -> f64>(f : F) {
   //Body
}
```

This works, but I would like to document the input parameters of `f` by giving them names.

Is this possible?

Comment: This could be a case for the [newtype pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html#newtype). That way, not only is each parameter's purpose documented, the type checker will enforce it at compile time. Though this approach will involve writing some boilerplate (or pulling in a dependency to write it for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use type aliases:

```rust
type FirstArg = usize;
type SecondArg = usize;
type ThirgArg = usize;

fn foo(f: impl Fn(FirstArg, SecondArg, ThirdArg)) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's currently a solution on stable rust, but when [`type_alias_impl_trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2515) lands, or if you enable it in nightly, you'll be able to write

```rust
/// My function type
///
/// Arg1: the number of foos \
/// Arg2: the number of bars \
/// Arg3: the number of bazs
type F = impl Fn(usize, usize, usize) -> f64

fn foo(f: F) {
   //Body
}
```

Hovering `F` should show its docs.

Comment: This is not the same as the code in the OP. This allows only a single fn type, and the OP is generic.